Why do I have to freeze my player's x and z rotation to make my player movement work and why does my camera stutter when colliding with things?
So I have an empty object called player with the PlayerMovement script and a rigidbody. I have the main camera and player visual as childs of it. The movement works fine as long as I freeze the rigidbody's x and z rotation, but why is that? Here is my player code (minus a couple of things that would just make it harder for you to help me):
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
    {
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 5f;
 

    private float xLook;
    private float yLook;

    [SerializeField] private float _mouseSensitivity;
    [SerializeField] private float _upAndDownMax;

    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rb;
    private Camera _camera;

    private Vector3 movement;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _camera = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        HandleMoveInput();
        HandleLookInput();
    }
     private void HandleMoveInput()
     {
        float hor = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float ver = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveInput = new Vector3(hor, 0, ver);
        moveInput = transform.forward * moveInput.z + transform.right * moveInput.x;
        moveInput.Normalize();
        movement = moveInput * speed;
     }
    private void HandleLookInput()
    {
        xLook += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * _mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        //  transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, xLook, 0);
        rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, xLook, 0));

        yLook -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * _mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        yLook = Mathf.Clamp(yLook, -_upAndDownMax, _upAndDownMax);
        _camera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(yLook, 0, 0);
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovePlayer();
       // LookPlayer();
    }
    private void MovePlayer()
    {
        Vector3 currentVelocity = rb.velocity;
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(movement.x, currentVelocity.y, movement.z);

        Vector3 force = targetVelocity - currentVelocity;
        force.y = 0; 

        rb.AddForce(force, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
    }
}

So I am guessing the problem is inside HandleMoveInput but I am not sure. I am just wondering why I have to freeze the rotation of z and x to make it work.
The second problem is that the camera sometimes start to stutter when colliding with things. I tested and I believe its because of the freeze problem and that its a child of the player. Because it does not happen when its not a child. Is it a bad idea to make the camera I child of the player?
If it's of any help:


It looks like we're missing the LookPlayer method. Have you tried setting the angular velocity to zero?

Sorry the LookPlayer method was just this " rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, xLook, 0));" which is under the "HandleLookInput" I had it in FixedUpdate once because its a rigidbody method, but that produced a camera with bad fps(but thats only because the method was called less, so I switched it back to Update)

When you mean "Angular Velocity" you are referring to "Angular drag", right? I have tried and I still got that camera jerk. It seems to happen whenever I collide with the side of an object while still going in that direction. You know when you go in the direction of a wall and your character gets "stuck", because your character is applying force in that direction and if you stop applying force your character falls down. But I think the reason is because the camera is a child and the collision or the input does something to the character which the camera dislike.

No, I use the words "angular velocity" to mean exactly that: angular velocity.

Well it seems like that worked? I dont get the camera stutter anymore and I dont have to freeze the rotation of certain axis. But that still brings me the question, why do I have to change the angular velocity/freeze rotation to make the character walk? Also Angular velocity, thats the current rotational velocity, right? I put this on update "  rb.angularVelocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);" but shouldnt that prevent me from moving the y axis? But I can still do that? I guess thats because "  rb.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(0, xLook, 0));" overrides that?

Does this answer your question?

Well I guess it kinda does. I understand why you might want to freeze an axis or set angular velocity to zero to make your character not rotate. But the problem I have is that if I dont freeze/set angular velocity = Vector3.zero then my character is "Stuck" and you can only walk one step in each direction, x and y, -1 or 1 and when you stopp pressing your character goes back. Its like moving like this: "transform.position = movement" it makes your character stuck, because it never accounts for the new position, thats why you use "+=" Its the same problem I have when I dont freeze x and y.

Imagine that the player is at (0, 0, 0) and can walk 1 step each frame. If I press "up" then my new position should be (0, 0, 1) and if I press "up" again it should be (0, 0, 2) but with the code I provided in my post^ if I dont freeze/Angular velocity its like using "transform = direction" not accounting for the new direction, so you are stuck at -1, 0, and goes back to 0 when you dont press anything(in x and z or x and y, depending on the game) I dont have to freeze when moving with the transform like "transform.position += direction;" or "Transform.Translate(direction);"

I think it would help to edit your post to clarify what your question is, as it sounds like what you want help with, or your understanding of it and what you need clarified next, has evolved.

Well its still the same "Why do I have to freeze my player's x and z rotation to make my player movement work" and I think you are right? Its seems like this is only a problem I have when using Rigidbody's and the problem is solved when you either freeze x and z, or have Angular.velocity = Vector3.zero or when you take Angular drag and put it at a number higher then 0. And you can see that when the player tilts/rotates, left/right on the z, which is the Horizontal input, if you freeze that axis you can walk in that direction. So I guess the tilting/rotation makes it impossible to walk?
